# Should I press the coffee tight?

Tags: ground-coffee, drip-brew

This is about dripping coffee maker. I used to just dump grounded coffee on top of the filter, but recently I started pressing the grounded coffee tight. My thought was that, this way, it would be harder for the water to drip through, and potentially stay contact with the grounded coffee for a longer period, hoping the coffee would be stronger this way.

Does anyone else do this? Does this make sense? Is there any reference of some sort of experiment proves either?

Comment: I tried "tamping" the grounds in an old school Bunn-o-matic coffee maker at work and it did not make a difference.  I thought the same thing.  What did make a difference was water, cleaning the machine regularly (I would poor/Brew through white wine vinegar several times once a week), and adding more grounds.  The ratio was a big thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're talking about is commonly referred to as "tamping". This is generally only used in making espresso, and is not recommended for any other brew method that I know of.

You are correct in assuming that the tamping will increase brew times and therefore the coffee will be in contact with the water for longer. This of course produces a stronger coffee.

However, this is not the "correct" way to increase the strength of coffee. The generally accepted way of doing this is changing the brew ratio. The brew ratio is the ratio of grounds to water, typically denoted in grams. The ratios range greatly depending on type of brewing. Tamping the coffee will also affect the flavour of the coffee, because one part of water will extract from one part of grounds longer, producing an undesirable taste.

If you want stronger coffee, simply add more grounds to your filter basket. This way your water is not in contact with the grounds for too long, but rather extracts from more grounds. The flavour will be noticeably better through this method.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just adding my two cents:

Tamping, unless for espresso, should be avoided. (PS: Moka pot is not espresso, avoid tamping)

As it was mentioned, the coffee will have an uneven extraction of the grains. A good article is available in Barista Hustle:

https://baristahustle.com/blogs/barista-hustle/the-most-important-thing-about-brewing-coffee

Answer (score 1):

Try to suppress the strong coffee beans so that the powder is smoother, the coffee will be more delicious. I do it here on how to make coffee.

[image]

Comment: You can compress it to the point that water does not seep through the coffee.